# Android room database IN Caluse not working as expected

Tags: android, android-room

I have this simple query in DAO and its not not returning any data.

```
@Query("select user_id from users where _id IN (:ids)")
    fun getAllUsers(ids: List<String>):List<String>
```

This is my list of ids

```
val userIds= mutableListOf<String>()
        userIds.add("1")
        userIds.add("2")
        userIds.add("3")
```

When i run this query from database inspector in android studio its executed as

```
select user_id from users where _id IN ('1,2,3')
```

however i think it should be executed as

```
select user_id from users where _id IN ('1','2','3')
```

I do have data in my table for _Id 1,2 and 3